# How to create a composite variable out of 3 non-correlated variables?

Tags: random-variable, normalization, standardization, composite

I am working on a model to account for flood risk and it is based on three variables:

Variable 1: drainage (float: 0 - 80)
Variable 2: estimated population (float: 0-2,000)
Variable 3: road network importance (float: 0-1)

All the 3 variables are highly left-skewed, but they are not correlated. Supposing that the 3 variables are equally important to analyze the flood risk , is there a way I can combine them to create a score?

Comment: There are an infinite number of functions of three variables... Can you clarify what mathematical properties you would like this function to have?

Comment: @Galen I would like that the resulting score to be well balanced, i.e., it should be composed of these 3 variables and the 3 would have the same weight/importance. Also it would be nice if the score would vary between [0,1]

Comment: You could skip the composite score and go right to computing flood risk.

Comment: @rolando2 how exactly? My plan is to use this score as the flooding risk

Comment: Do you know if there has been a flood?

Comment: I’d figured you knew.

Comment: @JeremyMiles yes